# NHibernate commits one child instead of two

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have again some problems with NHibernate. I want to add two child objects to a parent at the same time. The problem is that only the first child gets committed and the second child gets ignored. I don't even get an error message for the second child.

```
public void CreateKeyword(CreateKeywordRequest request)
{
    Collection collection = _collectionRepository.FindCollection(request.IdentityToken, request.CollectionName);

    collection.AddKeyword(request.CategoryName, request.KeywordName, request.KeywordDescription);

    _uow.Commit();
}
```

-

```
public void AddKeyword(string categoryName, string keywordName, string keywordDescription)
{

    Category category = Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryName == categoryName).FirstOrDefault();

    Keyword keyword = new Keyword { Category = category, KeywordName = keywordName, Description = keywordDescription };

    category.Keywords.Add(keyword);

    Test testOne= new Test{ Keyword = keyword, name = "test1" };
    Test testTwo= new Test{ Keyword = keyword, name = "test2" };

    //Only testOne gets committed and testTwo gets ignored
    keyword.Tests.Add(testOne);
    keyword.Tests.Add(testTwo);

    ThrowExceptionIfKeywordIsInvalid(keyword);
}
```

Comment: Be sure. It seems from code that you could be able to add child with name test2 and not test1 => 2nd child is added not first one? is this the case?

Comment: I am sure, only test1 gets inserted. (double checked)

Comment: I can add as many tests as I want, but only the first test gets committed.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect Tests is some kind of Set (eg ISet) and the Equals method of Test only compares on the Keyword property